# Proving sufficient conditions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, first-order-logic, malliavin-calculus

I am wondering if a "reverse necessary condition" implies sufficiency. Suppose your objective is to solve
$$
\min_{x\in X} f(x)
$$

where $X$ is a convex and compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f(\cdot)$ is a continuously differentiable function. The necessary condition for $x^*\in X$ to be optimal is that $$
(x-x^*)f'(x^*)\geq 0
$$
for all $x\in X$. However, suppose that $f$ is not convex so we don't know if the necessary conditions are also sufficient. Instead, consider the following condition:
$$
\tag A
f'(x)(x^*-x)\leq 0
$$
for all $x\in X$. Essentially, (A) implies that starting from any $x
\in X$ and moving in the "direction" of $x^*$ is always beneficial. More formally, assuming $f$ is Malliavin differentiable, (A) is implied by  $f(\epsilon x^*+(1-\epsilon)x)\leq f(x)$ for small enough $\epsilon >0$.

Does (A) imply that $x^*$ is optimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must be frank, I am not up to speed on the consequences of Malliavin differentiability. But it seems that under some mild conditions on $f$ it ought to be so. Suppose that there exists a point $y$ such that $f(y) < f(x^*)$. Define:
$$g(t) = f((1-t)x^* + ty) = f(x^* + t(y-x^*))$$
Then for $t\in[0,1]$, with $g(0) = f(x^*)$, and $g(1) = f(y)$, with $g(1) < g(0)$. Then for $t>0$, we have
\begin{aligned}
g'(t) &= \langle \nabla f(x^* + t(y-x^*)), y-x^*\rangle \\
&= -t^{-1} \langle \nabla f(x^* + t(y-x^*)), x^* - (x^* + t(y-x^*)) \rangle \geq 0.
\end{aligned}
(and the continuity of the derivative ensures that $g'(0)\geq 0$ as well). Therefore,
$$0 \leq \int_0^1 g'(t) dt = g(1) - g(0) < 0$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Minor comment: $g'(t) \ge 0 \forall t \ge 0$ implies $g$ being non-decreasing over $\mathbb{R}_+$, which implies $g(1)\ge g(0)$.

Comment: Definitely a simpler way to express it @khue